# How do I reorder the video devices on macOS?

Tags: high-sierra, video, macos

Every time I use a new app on macOS (10.13.6 here, but I don't think it makes a difference) that uses the webcam, I'm often caught out by it defaulting to an software video device that is *not* my webcam. I see that there is no concept of a default video input device on macOS (as there is with audio input & output devices). However, all programs seem to just pick the "first" device by default, and there seems to be a fixed-order list. I was wondering if I could somehow reorder this list, even it means editing plist files or such. Does anyone know if this is possible?